# How to access the data contained within a serialized object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

i have an object which holds a user name and job count, which then is inserted into a list. (from a datatable)

Assuming the code below is the right way to go about this, how do i access these data elements in javascript?

class:

```
public class thePeople
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Calls { get; set; }


    public thePeople(string n, string c)
    {
        Name = n;
        Calls = c;

    }
}
```

then the code using the class:

```
        var thosePeople = new List<thePeople>();

        StringBuilder Qry = new StringBuilder();

        Qry.Append("SELECT Count(Job_Id) as TotalJobs, User_Name,User_Id, jobstatus ");
        Qry.Append("FROM Jobs, Users ");
        Qry.Append("WHERE Jobs.jobstatus like 'o' AND Users.deleted = '0' AND Jobs.Next_User_Id = Users.User_Id ");
        Qry.Append("GROUP BY User_Name");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = OMALibrary.OMADAL.Execute.PerCustomer.Query(Qry.ToString(), OMALibrary.OMADAL.Enumerators.TypeOfServers.Helpdesk, theCustomer);

        for (int x = 0; x <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
        {
            thosePeople.Add(new thePeople(dt.Rows[x]["User_Name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[x]["Total_Jobs"].ToString()));
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thosePeople);
```

When i did this before for a "single row" object, I'd just use:

```
var users = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d)
```

then just access it by typing:

```
users.Name; users.Calls;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look at the serialized result to see what it looks like. Since you're serializing a `List`, it probably comes through as an array:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Joe",
        "Calls": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "Nitin",
        "Calls": 3
    }
]
```

...and so you'd access the elements as

```
var users = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);
console.log(users.length);  // The number of entries
console.log(users[0].Name); // The first user's name
console.log(users[1].Name); // The first user's name
```

Or loop through:

```
jQuery.each(users, function(index, user) {
    // Here, `user` is an entry from the array, so `user.Name` and `user.Calls`
});
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you, works gr8! I used the foreach from jquery you mentioned. jQuery.each(users, function (index, user) {
                                alert(users[index].Name + "-" + users[index].Calls);
                            });

Comment: @MarthinusElliott: Good deal, glad that helped! I have to admit having guessed a bit that it would come back as an array, but it seemed logical.